# C, can't compare two buffers

Tags: c, compare, atmelstudio

I am working with some C code and I'm totally stuck in this function. It should compare two buffers with some deviator. For example if EEPROM_buffer[1] = 80, so TxBuffer values from 78 to 82 should be correct!

So the problem is that it always returns -1. I checked both buffers, data is correct and they should match, but won't. Program just runs while until reach i = 3 and returns -1..

I compile with atmel studio 6.1, atmel32A4U microcontroller..

```
int8_t CheckMatching(t_IrBuff * tx_buffer, t_IrBuff * tpool)
{
uint8_t i = 0; 

uint16_t * TxBuffer = (uint16_t*) tx_buffer->data;

while((TxBuffer->state != Data_match) || (i != (SavedBuff_count))) // Data_match = 7;
{   
    uint16_t * EEPROM_buffer = (uint16_t*) tpool[i].data; 

    for(uint16_t j = 0; j < tpool[i].usedSize; j++) // tpool[i].usedSize = 67;
    {
        if(abs(TxBuffer[j] - EEPROM_buffer[j]) > 3)
        {
            i++;
            continue;               
        }
    }

    i++;        
    TxBuffer->state = Data_match; // state value before Data_match equal 6!
}

tx_buffer->state = Buffer_empty;

if(i == (SavedBuff_count)) // SavedBuff_count = 3;
{
    return -1;
}

return i;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Both your `TxBuffer` elements and `EEPROM_buffer` elements are `uint16_t`. When deducting `81` from `80` as `uint16_t` it would give `0xffff`, with no chance of `abs` to help you. Do a typecast to `int32_t` and you will be better off.

Comment: `uint16_t * EEPROM_buffer` and `uint16_t * TxBuffer` sorry have to get my typo correct. Thx